# How to create custom User Control derived from CommonDialog class

Tags: c#, user-controls, folderbrowserdialog

I would like to extend the FolderBrowserDialog to have the option to include subfolders for selected Folder (add Checkbox to set to include or not). I found out that I can't extend the basic FolderBrowserDialog as it is a sealed class.

So I thought the simplest solution would be to create a user control, that is derived from CommonDialog (the same class as is FolderBrowserDialog), copy the code from standard FolderBrowserDialog and just alter it a little bit so it would also have the "Include Subfolders" Checkbox.

But when I copied the code from default FolderBrowserDialog it gives me an error:

```
missing partial modifier on declaration of type [my_class_name] another partial declaration of this type exists c#
```

And it points out to the "[my_class_name].Designer.cs" file.

```
namespace my_custom_folder_open
{
    // Summary:
    //     Prompts the user to select a folder. This class cannot be inherited.
    [DefaultEvent("HelpRequest")]
    [DefaultProperty("SelectedPath")]
    [Designer("System.Windows.Forms.Design.FolderBrowserDialogDesigner, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")]
    public sealed class UserControl2 : CommonDialog
    {
        // Summary:
        //     Initializes a new instance of the System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
        //     class.
        public UserControl2();

        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the descriptive text displayed above the tree view control in
        //     the dialog box.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The description to display. The default is an empty string ("").
        [Browsable(true)]
        [DefaultValue("")]
        [Localizable(true)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the root folder where the browsing starts from.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     One of the System.Environment.SpecialFolder values. The default is Desktop.
        //
        // Exceptions:
        //   System.ComponentModel.InvalidEnumArgumentException:
        //     The value assigned is not one of the System.Environment.SpecialFolder values.
        [Browsable(true)]
        [Localizable(false)]
        public Environment.SpecialFolder RootFolder { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets the path selected by the user.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     The path of the folder first selected in the dialog box or the last folder
        //     selected by the user. The default is an empty string ("").
        [Browsable(true)]
        [DefaultValue("")]
        [Localizable(true)]
        public string SelectedPath { get; set; }
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets a value indicating whether the New Folder button appears in
        //     the folder browser dialog box.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     true if the New Folder button is shown in the dialog box; otherwise, false.
        //     The default is true.
        [Browsable(true)]
        [DefaultValue(true)]
        [Localizable(false)]
        public bool ShowNewFolderButton { get; set; }

        // Summary:
        //     Occurs when the user clicks the Help button on the dialog box.
        [Browsable(false)]
        [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
        public event EventHandler HelpRequest;

        // Summary:
        //     Resets properties to their default values.
        public override void Reset();
        protected override bool RunDialog(IntPtr hWndOwner);
    }
}
```

Where could be a problem?

Btw I've created the project as Windows Forms Control Library..

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3):

You are seriously on the wrong track with this.  These dialogs are Components, not controls.  They are very thin wrappers around the dialogs that are built into Windows.  Those dialogs themselves don't know anything about .NET and are written in unmanaged code.  The only reason they are a Component and not just a plain class is to allow you to drop one on a form.  Helpful to set a few properties with the designer.

Maybe the term "CommonDialog" was misleading.  Microsoft called it "common" only because they are commonly used dialogs in a GUI program.  And encouraged using the built-in ones so that every program has a very similar way to, say, open a file.

It doesn't make much sense to derive from CommonDialog because there is no need to create a custom dialog.  Because Windows only has the built-in ones and they are already wrapped by their respective .NET classes.  Your plan is going to wreck on what the native FolderBrowserDialog can do.  Which does not include showing checkboxes.  It was sealed for a good reason.

Answer (score 1):

Hans is quite correct that you cannot solve your problem by deriving a new class from `CommonDialog`. What you can do though is to use the raw `IFileDialog` component in folder picker mode. You'll also need to use `IFileDialogCustomize` to add your check box. Since this is just COM it's actually very simple to use from .net.